# php build in server is not showing document root

Tags: php, command-prompt

**the problem:**
I try to set up the build in php test server whit the commanprompt i use the command 
`php -S localhost:4100` and it outputs this

[image]

but acording to wiki's and so it shoud output this

[image]

*note: this is a recreation*

**info:**
i am running PHP 7.4.6 (cli) (built: May 12 2020 11:38:54) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
and my php filles (where i unzipped it in the installation) is C:\static\php

**-**
thanks already julian

Comment: You've tagged this with "Windows" while the other output contains `/home/me/public_html`, suggesting that it might be a *nix based OS. The PHP versions are also completely different. PHP 7.4 vs PHP 5.4. Do you actually have an issue? Or are you just asking why different PHP versions (that came 7,5 years apart) on different OS's might have different output even though everything works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing Windows output instead of Linux output. If Your server service is available under localhost:4100 then everything is OK so far :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same bunch of statements when I pass "php -S localhost:4000" , I was getting trouble in finding the document root . The latest versions of php are not showing the Document Root after the php server gets started. And I noticed that the Document Root is "c:/users/home/ " in my case. And I have created a class path in environment variables as "c:/php" where the php is located.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I have observed that the document root is the location where you set up the localhost. Therefore, if you are in the `C:\Users\YourName` directory, this is the folder you're looking for.

The second screenshot appears to be a Linux console. Notice that the document root informed in the fifth line begins with a `/`, indicating that the folder in which the user opened the console has been omitted.